# Basic SQL assignment from university student

Tags: mysql, sql

My group is learning SQL and we have made some tables and are gona do some queries for an assignment.

The assignment is: Define a view that shows customer, order and total amount for each order.

Here is an example of what we try (doesn't work).

```
create view vetsje as
select cus_lname, cus_fname, cus_email, orders.order_id, order_status,
count(ol_quantity) * prod_price as total_price
from customer
inner join orders on customer.cus_id = orders.cus_id
inner join orderline on orders.order_id = orderline.order_id
inner join product on orderline.prod_id = product.prod_id
group by order_id;
```

Here are our tables:

```
create table if not exists customer (
    cus_id int(5) not null auto_increment,
    cus_lname varchar(30) not null,
    cus_fname varchar(30) not null,
    cus_pnumber int(12),
    cus_address varchar(50) not null,
    cus_email varchar(50),
    constraint customer_pk primary key (cus_id)
);

create table if not exists orders (
    order_id int(5) not null auto_increment,
    order_date date,
    order_status boolean default false,
    cus_id int(4) not null,
    foreign key (cus_id) references customer(cus_id),
    constraint order_pk primary key (order_id)
);

create table if not exists product (
    prod_id varchar(10) not null,
    prod_name varchar(20),
    prod_price int(10),
    constraint product_pk primary key (prod_id)
);

create table if not exists orderline (
    order_id int(5) not null,
    prod_id varchar(10) not null,
    ol_quantity int(10),
    foreign key (order_id) references orders(order_id),
    foreign key (prod_id) references product(prod_id),
    constraint orderLine_pks primary key (order_id,prod_id)
);
```

Comment: Have you tried JOIN though?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work?  Is there an error message are results incorrect (if so what specifically is wrong?)

Comment: "dont work" is not a problem description. Please add expected/actual output and error messages. HINT: If you use aggregation functions (sum, max avg etc) and a `group by` all selected attributes have to be either in the `group by` or in the aggregate function.

Comment: `count(ol_quantity) * prod_price as total_price` is likely the culprit.  you probably want `sum(ol_Quantity * prod_Price)` as Total_Price  10 widgets * $2.00 price = $20.  next line 5 widgets at $3.00 price = $15 sum of 15 and 20 is $35 for total order price.    While I'm all for using the non-aggregated columns in the group by  mySQLs extended group by would make it unnecessary here.   ***This is one of the few cases I've seen recently where grouping by just the order_ID should work.**  Why: all of the other info selected is repeated; and a perfect example of when MySQL GRP extensions work.

Comment: @zerow it helps to state the requirements in normal English.  So it appears you need to display: customer and order information for all orders, including customer names, email, order status orderID and the sum total for the order which is calculated by summing the order line quantity times the product price for all lines on an order.  If this is what you're after, then I think you just need to change the info in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at it without the error it looks like the calculation and the group by would be your issue, try this:

```
SELECT cus_lname,
       cus_fname,
       cus_email,
       orders.order_id,
       order_status,
       ((COUNT(ol_quantity)) * prod_price) AS total_price
FROM customer
     INNER JOIN orders ON customer.cus_id = orders.cus_id
     INNER JOIN orderline ON orders.order_id = orderline.order_id
     INNER JOIN product ON orderline.prod_id = product.prod_id
GROUP BY cus_lname,
         cus_fname,
         cus_email,
         orders.order_id,
         order_status;
```

Comment: Don't do people's homework for them! You think you're helping them but you're not.

Comment: @JohnConde this likely woudln't help them anyway.  The problem isn't in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help and 
Thanks to xQbert for solved the problem for me.

Changing the

```
count(ol_quantity) * prod_price
```

with

```
sum(ol_Quantity * prod_Price)
```

Solved the problem of it not adding the quantity and price right

Sorry for the bad grammer, but I am not from an english speaking country.